# One Docker container stopped resolving DNS properly

Tags: linux, postfix, docker, linux-networking

I have weird problem with my Mailcow instance. One container (Postfix) has started resolving DNS partially. The problem is only with this particular container which I don't understand. It is causing that emails are not being sent from it due to `domain name not found` error.

```
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host wp.pl
Host wp.pl not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host mx.wp.pl
Host mx.wp.pl not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

```
root@6c751ea397ad:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search domain.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

but with external DNS:

```
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host wp.pl 1.1.1.1
Using domain server:
Name: 1.1.1.1
Address: 1.1.1.1#53
Aliases: 

wp.pl has address 212.77.98.9
wp.pl mail is handled by 0 mx.wp.pl.
wp.pl mail is handled by 5 mx5.wp.pl.
```

for different domain:

```
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host -t any o2.pl             
o2.pl has address 212.77.98.29
o2.pl descriptive text "facebook-domain-verification=0omejgqroqocgh4efgrbu8bovlazni"
o2.pl descriptive text "v=spf1 include:wp.pl -all"
o2.pl mail is handled by 10 mx.tlen.pl.
o2.pl has SOA record ns1.go2.pl. root.go2.pl. 2020111002 3600 1080 1209600 7200
o2.pl name server ns1.go2.pl.
o2.pl name server ns2.go2.pl.
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host -t any mx.tlen.pl
mx.tlen.pl has address 193.222.135.150
```

This one is really weird:

```
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host -t any company.mail.protection.outlook.com 
Host company.mail.protection.outlook.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
root@6c751ea397ad:/# host -t any outlook.com 
outlook.com has SOA record bn7mgt0101dc013.prdmgt01.prod.exchangelabs.com. msnhst.microsoft.com. 2014796278 300 900 2419200 60
outlook.com has address 40.97.148.226
outlook.com has address 40.97.153.146
outlook.com has address 40.97.161.50
...
```

Each other container works fine:

```
root@c228923398e8:/# host wp.pl
wp.pl has address 212.77.98.9
wp.pl mail is handled by 5 mx5.wp.pl.
wp.pl mail is handled by 0 mx.wp.pl.
root@c228923398e8:/# host mx.wp.pl
mx.wp.pl has address 212.77.101.4
root@c228923398e8:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search domain.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

I've tried so far:

- removing and reinstalling `resolvconf` from the host
- Adding 1.1.1.1/8.8.8.8 to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
- Adding DNS to: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
- Adding static DNS to mailcow docker-compose
- Disabling firewall

all without any luck.